# Getting $E = f(T)$

Tags: calculus

I'm just stuck while trying to get $E = f(T)$ as $E = kT$ in this equation, where $k$ should be some number (constant), do you have any idea? Thanks!

$$E = 0.05 T e ^{0.2T}$$

Comment: Do you mean $e = 0.05Te^{0.2T}$?  That is, "decimal points" instead of commas?

Comment: @amWhy, I think commas are used as decimal marks in quite a handful of countries.

Comment: @yunone: thanks for that info... I need to learn these things! Just curious: how would one write $11,234.098$, e.g.?  Or is it customary in many countries not to use commas to separate digits, but only to indicate fractional component? My apologies for my cultural ignorance here.

Comment: @amWhy and @yunone, I've corrected the commas, they're decimal marks in my country, sorry

Comment: @Joaquin: No problem!  It was good for me to learn that the convention varies...but thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @amWhy: In many European and South American countries, the decimal mark is represented by a comma, and the digit separator is a period. So eleven thousand, two hundred thirty four and ninety eight thousandths would be written $11.234,098$. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) for a list of countries that use a comma as the decimal mark, vs. those that use a period.

Comment: @Arturo: Thanks for the explanation/enlightenment; I'll be sure to check out the Wikipedia article!

Comment: @Arturo, @amWhy: Speaking as a representative of decimal comma faction, I think that a space is more common as digit separator than a period. This has the additional bonus that if your program output follows the convention used in the US there is less chance of confusion. Helps my students, when I'm too lazy to convert Mathematica output to the local standard. The problems don't end there, though. Here a period is used as a separator in dates (dd.mm.yyyy) and to show ordinals (1.=first, 2.=second,...). I am having so much fun combining data sheets from all over the world into Excel :-)

Comment: @Jyrki: I think a more serious problem with dates stems from the fact that the US insists in having month before day (and let's not forget the misnomer of "billion"...) (-: Spaces are also commonly used in countries that use a decimal point; spaces were disfavored when typewriters (or printers) used mono-spaced font.

Comment: @Arturo: You're right. That difference bugged the hell out of me, when I lived in the US. I am unfortunate to have my birthday on October 2nd, but my US drivers licence (for example) listed it as February 10th. I did get that one fixed, but I just wonder whether some other documents were left with incorrect data. The problem with decimal comma vs period is among the least likely sources of confusion over here. All the early calculators used a period, because they were made in the US. Consequently public awareness of that difference in standards is very high here.

Comment: @Jyrki: The date thing still confuses me; I have a friend who is in enviable position of having her birthday on October 10th...

Answer (score 1):

$E = a T e^{b T}$, solve for $T$: we get $T = W(bE/a)/b$ .  Here $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Is this what he was asking? I thought he was looking for a number k so that f(T) is kT. The function is not linear though so there is no such k.

Comment: Sorry @GEdgar, but I can't understand how I can get $$E = kT$$ using the answer you provided...

Comment: @Matt was right, then. Joaquin: as already explained, what you ask for cannot be done.